# How to add CURL in php file to send form details both to email and to external data

Tags: php

I like to know how to send the form details to an external url as well as to email id. I had an experience in programming to the form details send to email id, but one of my client is asking to redirect the copy of form details to the url as like this http://someipaddress.com/XDKRT/SalLeadEntWeb.ASP , my website is developed by wordpress, can anyone guide me how to achieve this?, I came to know that using **CURL** we can achieve this but where to add CURL? my php action form is like this:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<?php
$contact_name = $_POST['name'];
$contact_email = $_POST['email'];
$contact_phone = $_POST['phone'];
$contact_message = $_POST['message'];

if( $contact_name == true )
{
    $sender = $contact_email;

    $receiver  = 'info@compositedge.com' . ',referral@compositeinvestments.com'; // note the comma

    $client_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $email_body = "Name: $contact_name \nEmail: $contact_email \nPhone No: $contact_phone \nMessage: $contact_message \n";  

    $extra = "From: info@compositedge.com\r\n" . "Reply-To: $sender \r\n" . "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

    if( mail( $receiver, "Open an Account - Download and Print", $email_body, $extra ) ) 
    {
    //IF SUCCESSFUL, REDIRECT
header("Location: http://www.mydomain.com/?page_id=1112");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "success=no";
    }
}
?>
<?php ob_flush(); ?>
```

Request to help me on this, where to add CURL?

Comment: can't help you with where to put curl, but i'll premptively answer a question that may come come up later. be advised that curl does not come standard with most webservers where you run php e.g. xampp. You're going to want to find the php.ini file and remove the semi colon regarding curl to activate it. then restart your computer or if you can just the server in order to activate it

Comment: cURL is very common with PHP.  There is no entry in php.ini relating to curl unless you are on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code with a cURL request added before the call to `mail()`.

```
<?php ob_start();

$contact_name = $_POST['name'];
$contact_email = $_POST['email'];
$contact_phone = $_POST['phone'];
$contact_message = $_POST['message'];

if( !empty($contact_name)) {
    $sender = $contact_email;
    $receiver  = 'info@compositedge.com' . ',referral@compositeinvestments.com'; // note the comma
    $client_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $email_body = "Name: $contact_name \nEmail: $contact_email \nPhone No: $contact_phone \nMessage: $contact_message \n";  
    $extra = "From: info@compositedge.com\r\n" . "Reply-To: $sender \r\n" . "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

    // URL for cURL to post to
    $url        = 'http://someipaddress.com/XDKRT/SalLeadEntWeb.ASP';

    // Postfields for cURL to send
    // NOTE: You probably need to change the array keys to what the remote server expects to receive
    $postFields = array('name' => $contact_name,
                        'email' => $contact_email,
                        'phone' => $contact_phone,
                        'message' => $contact_message);

    // initialize curl and options
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postFields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);

    // send curl request
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    // you can examine $res here to see if the request was successful


    if( mail( $receiver, "Open an Account - Download and Print", $email_body, $extra ) ) {
        // IF SUCCESSFUL, REDIRECT
        header("Location: http://www.mydomain.com/?page_id=1112");
    } else {
        echo "success=no";
    }
}

ob_flush();
```

The only thing you probably need to change aside from the `$url` for cURL are the names of the `$postFields`.  You should change this based on what the remote URL expects to be sent.

Hope that helps.